# How to submit a form in Sveltekit without a button?

Tags: node.js, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I have a form in the `+page.svelte` file and I want to do a submission but without a `<button />`.

For example I have a `<select>` element inside `<form>`, now when the user choose the selection, it triggers to submit the value to the `+page.server.ts` file

A rough example would be like this:

+page.svelte

```
<form method="POST" use:enhance>
    // I'm using svelte select
    <Select
        name="select"
        bind:justValue={value}
        items={items}
    />
</form>
```

Then, on the server file, it would be like this:

+page.server.ts

```js
import { fail, redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import type { Actions } from './$types';

export const actions: Actions = {
    default: async ({ request }) => {
        const formData = Object.fromEntries(await request.formData());

        const res  = await fetch(`${environment.apiUrl}/search`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                value: formData.select
            })
        });
        const item = await res.json();

        if(!res.ok) {
            return fail(401, { error: 'error', item });
        }
        
        return {
            success: true,
            item
        };
    },
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idk if this is the best solution, but you can use [requestSubmit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/requestSubmit)

Get form reference through `bind:this`

```
<form method="POST" use:enhance bind:this={formElement}>
```

and then you can trigger `formElement.requestSubmit()` at any moment.
In your case you can do it when `Select` triggers select event

Comment: Oh so I put the `formElement.requestSubmit()` on `on:change` trigger just like that right?

Comment: It works, and I can get the data from it. Cheers